# Gifting for WooCommerce Subscriptions Add User Role

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using [Gifting for WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions-gifting/) which makes it possible for one person to purchase a subscription product for someone else.

When the subscription is purchased, I add a user role to the user who purchased the product:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'add_role_on_purchase' );
function add_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $products_to_check = array( '12345' );

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && in_array( $item['product_id'], $products_to_check ) ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Add role
            $user->add_role( 'purchaser' );

            // Exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Gifting for WooCommerce Subscriptions creates a user and a user account for the recipient.

I need to add a user role to the recipient as well. Can this be done after the purchaser's subscription is set to active?

Answer (score 0):

Buying a subscription as a gift, a buyer provides a recipient's email address. You can take the provided email and find the recipient using the [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) function. Having a WP_User instance of the recipient, you can repeat the same logic you do for buyers.

A recipient email address provided by a buyer is probably stored somewhere in an order's meta.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll see what I can come up with but I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if I get some other ideas.